# Texture paint on a wall

Tags: home

There is texture paint in one of the walls in my house. Some part of the paint has been spoiled due to moisture from neighbourhood while on construction. Actually, the texture paint is a mixture of two colours. I cannot describe the colours or their numbers. I simply want to know how to make the same colours. Will it be necessary to take the help of a painter or we can do it at home by ourselves.

Comment: Your question is vague. A picture would help. Can the two colours be seen beside each other? Do they overlap? Are the the two colours applied in small spots that the eye blends from a distance? Are they truly mixed to form a third colour?

Comment: The area of each of the two colour spots must have enough area to be measured without the second colour appearing in the sample to be analysed. If there is more, the reading will not be accurate for one colour. The bigger the single colour area, the more accurate will be the reading of it. At best, the answer with the information you provide is maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Paint stores often have a color matching computer. It visually scans a paint chip, and tells the employees exactly what colors to mix together to recreate that color.

Find a paint store with that system. Ask them how big a sample of your paint (I think that's called a "chip") they will need for their computer. Ask them the best way to get that sample / those samples off your wall without damaging the wall. Then get the sample(s), bring them to the store, and have them mix up the paints that you need. Paint over the "chips" that you took off of your wall, as well as the area that has been spoiled.

Comment: The paint-chip software can make any of the colours for which they have a chip. It cannot analyze random samples in terms of their existing colour primaries that they have in stock.

Comment: @Stan The software I have seen was in use at the paint section in Home Depot. It can take a random sample, and tell the user what combination of pigments to mix into white paint in order to recreate that random sample. According to someone who had used it, when they painted it over their existing wall it almost looked as though no paint was going on, since it matched so well.

Comment: Then I'm Wrong. : ) Your answer makes more sense that buying a bunch o' stuff.

Comment: I'm sure there's a lot of paint-chip software out there. Some systems can do the random color and some can't!

Comment: I visited a Sherwin Williams paint store today. They verified your answer. They verified that a small section of wall painted surface must be removed. The owner said there's also a variety of apps available that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about colour matching.

Try using a phone or tablet app that can display a colour wheel.

Fill the screen with a colour that's close to the target colour, put your device against an uncontaminated part of the wall, then adjust the colour until you have a match. (Whether it's an 'exact' match depends on your colour discrimination.)

Once you get a match, take the device to your favourite paint seller and ask them to mix a batch of exactly that colour for you. You might have to take into account the difference in lighting between your room and the shop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some technology.
(A Web search will give you more detailed information than space here allows.)

The NIX colour scanner ($99 US), NIX professional ($350 US)

Color Muse colour matching tool ($50 US) for paint samples

Color Grab (app) by Loomatix for Android turns a smartphone into a tool to identify colours. This smartphone app. has the highest ratings of ones now available.

Good luck.